# How to calculate distance between two markers within ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

so i have randomly generated 5 markers all within an ArrayList however i would to calculate the distance between the markers and only display the markers that are within 500 meters from each other, may code so far:

```
ArrayList<Marker> ArrM = new ArrayList<Marker>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(computeOffset(mLatLng,ranDist,newRandomHeading))
                        .visible(true)
                        .title("Marker"));
       ArrM.add(marker);
    }
```

the code above successfully creates 5 markers placed randomly around a given radius, however i would only like to display the markers that are within 500 meters from each other, i get a guaranteed of 3 markers that are 500 meters apart but how can i show only 2 of them?

Comment: Judging by what I can see in documentation, this API isn't really suitable for any kind of computation. Try [Google Maps Services API](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java), it should have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Maps Android API utility library that has a function to calculate distance between two LatLng:

http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

The computeDistanceBetween() from SphericalUtil is the function you should use in your code.

Please read the following documentation for further details

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/#spherical

Hope it helps!